# How to generate Report with Unicode Character for Gujarati text?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, internationalization, unicode

I am using ArcMap 10.1 and want to generate report using Report Designer.

In Report header i use **Label Control** for display unicode character (Gujarati) but when i copied gujarati text from word doc and assign to label text property, it display as question marks, 'garbled' or 'nonsense'.

Is there a simple way to display Gujarati characters in an ArcMap label?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but I got following links for your reference :

1.Tech Article : [Import Unicode data into a personal geodatabase](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/28657)

2.You can try  HEX ASCII symbol you want to display

For details visit [ArcGIS forums](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=1730&t=203929)

3.Similar thing is explained @ [ArcGIS Ideas](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=08730000000bxr2&returnUrl=/apex/ideaList?c=09a300000004xET&category=Maps%2band%2bContent&sort=comments)

Still researching more on this at my end..thanks